# Download files as .zip via cmis

Tags: zip, cmis, opencmis, smd

I'm currently developing a native android application and try to access some pictures on a document server. For communication I'm using the `OpenCMIS` library.

My goal is to download the pictures and save them to the device's internal storage or sd card. My question is, whether there is a possibility to download the files as a compressed archive like a .zip for example and extract this on the device? So instead of downloading a lot of files separately, I'd like to download one big file.

Is this something `OpenCMIS` is capable of? Or is this depending on the document server? I'm working with SAP Mobile Documents and know that I can download a whole folder as a .zip from the web interface over a browser, but I haven't found something about that being possible in a custom android client.

Any hints or explanations are appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Download as Zip isn't a CMIS service. I think your only option is to open a new zip file for writing, then stream the contents of each CMIS document into it

Comment: SAP Mobile Documents provides a hidden rendition on folders (stream ID: "sap:zipRendition"). You can use getContentStream() to access it.

Comment: thanks @Florian that sounds like something to work with! are there any examples available online for that since I can't seem to find any. or could you maybe provide a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Something like this should work: 
ContentStream zipStream = session.getContentStream(folder, "sap:zipRendition", null, null);

Comment: got it working, thank you very much! a further question would be, can I only get a already existing folder as a zip or can I also get the results of a query (e.g. all files that were updated since a certain timestamp) as a zip?

Comment: That only works for folders.

Answer (score 1):

So I got it working with [help from Florian Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893398/download-files-as-zip-via-cmis#comment49918448_30893398).

For anyone interessted, the final code to download a folder as a .zip archive from a SAP Mobile Document Server in a native android app would look something like this:

```
public void downloadAsZip(Session session, Folder folder, File destination){
    ContentStream zipStream = session.getContentStream(folder, "sap:zipRendition", null, null);
    InputStream inputStream = zipStream.getStream();

    try {
        File file = new File(destination, folder.getName()+".zip");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;

        while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }

        fileOutputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```